# Stop send email attempt when cron is run

Tags: cron

I just took over a drupal 7 site and when cron is run I get the follow error
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host
WD mail: Error sending e-mail (from ???????? to ???????)

I know the previous developer turned some feature/function on that will send an email each time a cron job is run.  Does anyone know how or where to turn this off?

I have checked in the admin-> cron, but there are no settings there to adjust.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it must be a custom module or Drupal core's update notification. If your site can send emails without a problem, I would look for any coding by your previous developer that utilises a custom SMTP server.

Comment: I checked through the modules, nothing in the custom module folder and nothing in the main module folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely defined as a [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) implementation in a custom module. Trying searching through your codebase for "_cron" to see what you can find. If you install [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) you should be able to get a full list of all cron jobs and could disable any jobs you don't way run.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - i was not aware of Elysia - amazing how many modules Drupal has to solve or help solve your issues.  Thanks again.